# How do I fix Virtual Box on Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS?

Tags: apt, package-management, virtualbox

I recently tried to launch a virtual machine using Virtual Box. However when I clicked "Start" I got the error "rc=-1908". The error message said to do the command `modprobe vboxdrv`.

- When I ran the command `modprobe vboxdrv` I got

  ```
  modprobe: FATAL: Module vboxdrv not found in directory /lib/modules/6.4.10-x64v3-xanmod1
  ```
- I then tried to reinstall `virtualbox`, `virtualbox-qt`, `virtualbox-dkms` and `virtualbox-ext-pack` but they failed.
- When I tried `sudo nala install -f` I got these errors:

  ```
  Error: Installation has failed.
  If you'd like to file a bug report please include '/var/log/nala/dpkg-debug.log'

  Error: error processing package virtualbox-dkms (--configure):

  Error: error processing package virtualbox-dkms (--configure):
   installed virtualbox-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
   installed virtualbox-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10

  Error: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox:

  Error: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox:
   virtualbox depends on virtualbox-dkms (>= 7.0.8-dfsg-2pop1~1688756590~22.04~9c911a1) | virtualbox-source (>= 7.0.8-dfsg-2pop1~1688756590~22.04~9c911a1) | virtualbox-modules; however:
   virtualbox depends on virtualbox-dkms (>= 7.0.8-dfsg-2pop1~1688756590~22.04~9c911a1) | virtualbox-source (>= 7.0.8-dfsg-2pop1~1688756590~22.04~9c911a1) | virtualbox-modules; however:
    Package virtualbox-dkms is not configured yet.
    Package virtualbox-dkms is not configured yet.
    Package virtualbox-source is not installed.
    Package virtualbox-source is not installed.
    Package virtualbox-modules is not installed.
    Package virtualbox-modules is not installed.
    Package virtualbox-dkms which provides virtualbox-modules is not configured yet.
    Package virtualbox-dkms which provides virtualbox-modules is not configured yet.

  Error: error processing package virtualbox (--configure):

  Error: error processing package virtualbox (--configure):
   dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
   dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

  Error: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox-ext-pack:

  Error: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox-ext-pack:
   virtualbox-ext-pack depends on virtualbox (>= 7.0.8-dfsg-0~) | virtualbox-7.0; however:
   virtualbox-ext-pack depends on virtualbox (>= 7.0.8-dfsg-0~) | virtualbox-7.0; however:
    Package virtualbox is not configured yet.
    Package virtualbox is not configured yet.
    Package virtualbox-7.0 is not installed.
    Package virtualbox-7.0 is not installed.
   virtualbox-ext-pack depends on virtualbox (<< 7.0.8-dfsg-z) | virtualbox-7.0; however:
   virtualbox-ext-pack depends on virtualbox (<< 7.0.8-dfsg-z) | virtualbox-7.0; however:
   virtualbox-ext-pack depends on virtualbox (<< 7.0.8-dfsg-z) | virtualbox-7.0; however:
    Package virtualbox is not configured yet.
    Package virtualbox is not configured yet.
    Package virtualbox is not configured yet.
    Package virtualbox-7.0 is not installed.
    Package virtualbox-7.0 is not installed.
    Package virtualbox-7.0 is not installed.

  Error: error processing package virtualbox-ext-pack (--configure):

  Error: error processing package virtualbox-ext-pack (--configure):

  Error: error processing package virtualbox-ext-pack (--configure):
   dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
   dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
   dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

  Error: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox-qt:

  Error: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox-qt:

  Error: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox-qt:
   virtualbox-qt depends on virtualbox (= 7.0.8-dfsg-2pop1~1688756590~22.04~9c911a1); however:
   virtualbox-qt depends on virtualbox (= 7.0.8-dfsg-2pop1~1688756590~22.04~9c911a1); however:
   virtualbox-qt depends on virtualbox (= 7.0.8-dfsg-2pop1~1688756590~22.04~9c911a1); however:
    Package virtualbox is not configured yet.
    Package virtualbox is not configured yet.
    Package virtualbox is not configured yet.

  Error: error processing package virtualbox-qt (--configure):

  Error: error processing package virtualbox-qt (--configure):

  Error: error processing package virtualbox-qt (--configure):
   dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
   dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
   dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
  No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
  No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
  No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
  No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
  No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
  No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
  No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
  No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
  No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

  Errors were encountered while processing:

  Errors were encountered while processing:

  Errors were encountered while processing:
   virtualbox-dkms
   virtualbox-dkms
   virtualbox-dkms
   virtualbox
   virtualbox
   virtualbox
   virtualbox-ext-pack
   virtualbox-ext-pack
   virtualbox-ext-pack
   virtualbox-qt
   virtualbox-qt
   virtualbox-qt
  ```
- `cat /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.8/build/dkms.conf` outputs

```
PACKAGE_NAME="virtualbox"
PACKAGE_VERSION="7.0.8"
CLEAN="rm -f *.*o"
BUILT_MODULE_NAME[0]="vboxdrv"
BUILT_MODULE_LOCATION[0]="vboxdrv"
DEST_MODULE_LOCATION[0]="/updates"
BUILT_MODULE_NAME[1]="vboxnetadp"
BUILT_MODULE_LOCATION[1]="vboxnetadp"
DEST_MODULE_LOCATION[1]="/updates"
BUILT_MODULE_NAME[2]="vboxnetflt"
BUILT_MODULE_LOCATION[2]="vboxnetflt"
DEST_MODULE_LOCATION[2]="/updates"
AUTOINSTALL="yes"
```

- `cat /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.8/build/make.log` outputs

```
DKMS make.log for virtualbox-7.0.8 for kernel 6.4.12-x64v3-xanmod1 (x86_64)
Sun Aug 27 04:43:11 UTC 2023
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.4.12-x64v3-xanmod1'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: gcc-13 (Debian 13.2.0-2) 13.2.0
  You are using:           gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.8/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.8/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.8/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrvGip.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.8/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrvSem.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.8/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrvTracer.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.8/build/vboxdrv/SUPLibAll.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.8/build/vboxdrv/common/string/strformatrt.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.8/build/vboxdrv/combined-agnostic1.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.8/build/vboxdrv/combined-agnostic2.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.8/build/vboxdrv/combined-os-specific.o
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.8/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrvTracer.o: warning: objtool: SUPR0TracerFireProbe+0x7: indirect jump found in RETPOLINE build
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.8/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrvTracer.o: warning: objtool: supdrvTracerProbeFireStub+0x0: 'naked' return found in RETHUNK build
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.8/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrvTracer.o: warning: objtool: SUPR0TracerFireProbe+0x7: missing int3 after indirect jump
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.8/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrvTracer.o: warning: objtool: supdrvTracerProbeFireStub+0x0: missing int3 after ret
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.8/build/vboxdrv/combined-os-specific.o: warning: objtool: rtThreadCtxHooksLnxSchedOut+0x1a: call to {dynamic}() with UACCESS enabled
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.8/build/vboxdrv/combined-os-specific.o: warning: objtool: rtThreadCtxHooksLnxSchedIn+0x24: call to {dynamic}() with UACCESS enabled
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.8/build/vboxdrv/combined-os-specific.o: warning: objtool: VBoxHost_RTR0MemKernelCopyTo+0xa: redundant CLD
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.8/build/vboxdrv/combined-os-specific.o: warning: objtool: VBoxHost_RTR0MemKernelCopyFrom+0xa: redundant CLD
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.8/build/vboxdrv/vboxdrv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.8/build/vboxnetflt/linux/VBoxNetFlt-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.8/build/vboxnetflt/VBoxNetFlt.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.8/build/vboxnetflt/SUPR0IdcClient.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.8/build/vboxnetflt/SUPR0IdcClientComponent.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.8/build/vboxnetflt/linux/SUPR0IdcClient-linux.o
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.8/build/vboxnetflt/linux/VBoxNetFlt-linux.c: In function ‘vboxNetFltLinuxForwardToIntNetInner’:
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.8/build/vboxnetflt/linux/VBoxNetFlt-linux.c:1568:40: error: implicit declaration of function ‘skb_gso_segment’; did you mean ‘skb_gso_reset’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
 1568 |             struct sk_buff *pSegment = skb_gso_segment(pBuf, 0 /*supported features*/);
      |                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                        skb_gso_reset
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.8/build/vboxnetflt/linux/VBoxNetFlt-linux.c:1568:40: warning: initialization of ‘struct sk_buff *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:252: /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.8/build/vboxnetflt/linux/VBoxNetFlt-linux.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:497: /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.8/build/vboxnetflt] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:2187: /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.8/build] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.4.12-x64v3-xanmod1'
```

When I run `uname -r` I get `6.4.10-x64v3-xanmod1` and I do not have secure boot enabled. How can I fix this?

Comment: Looks like issue while configuring virtualbox-dkms. Can you find and paste the config/make log of virtualbox-dkms ?

Comment: Ok, I've added the config and make log off virtualbox-dkms

Comment: so from logs I can see your kernel module for virtual box is not getting built and exiting with error that's why modprobe  can't find module. the ```skb_gso_segment``` is missing somehow on your distro.